# C# POS code for Printer executing on Simulator instead of The Printer

Tags: c#, pos-for-.net

I have T-20 Espon printer, I'm beginner, I wanted to print `Hello printer` string (Nothing is working and I'm just getting started so I just want something printed), I started with that code :

```
PosExplorer explorer = null;
DeviceInfo _device;
PosPrinter _oposPrinter;

explorer = new PosExplorer();
_device = explorer.GetDevice(DeviceType.PosPrinter);
_oposPrinter = (PosPrinter) explorer.CreateInstance(_device);
_oposPrinter.Open();
_oposPrinter = (PosPrinter) explorer.CreateInstance(_device);
_oposPrinter.Open();
_oposPrinter.Claim(10000);
_oposPrinter.DeviceEnabled = true;
//normal print
_oposPrinter.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, "Hello world");
```

But when I execute the code I have this popping up :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1- In the **Epson** series i used the [OPOS ADK](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=soft&scat=38)

2- After installer i started the Setup : **Startup -> All Programs -> OPOS -> SetupPOS**.

3- A went to Device -> **POSPrinter**

4- Right Click : **Add New Device** and Fill details

5- In **Add New LDN** enter a Logical Name (*my example : T20PRINTER*)

6- In **Visual Studio** use the same code, but replace :

```
_device = explorer.GetDevice(DeviceType.PosPrinter);
```

with :

```
_device = explorer.GetDevice(DeviceType.PosPrinter, "T20PRINTER");
```

with way you are sure that you are calling your Printer with its **Logical Name**

Comment: Did you have to do anything special to get the service running, having same issue and adding the printer in epson SetupPOS isn't making it appear on the explorer.GetDevices. Only the Simulator shows up.

Comment: i had the same problem i guess in the beginning and honestly i solved by luck ! i think it depends on the version of the **EPSON OPOS ADK** , i downloaded multiple versions ! i remember that some of them had the same problem you are describing, anyway for my T20 : **EPSON OPOS ADK 2.70E UPOS1.13** works great !